# How to make a list of a minimum values only

Tags: python, list

There's a task. The user enters 's' values which represent the amount of the available space in the imaginary database, after that 'n' the number of users should be inputted. After this action user inputs the amount of "space" each user requires. The program should calculate how many users can fit the database.
My logic was the following:
First of all, after the "space requirement" the input list of inputs gets sorted. Then 'minn' list appears to gather the values in the future.
Second, if the sum of the required space equals to 's' it prints the number of users 'n'.
If not it should go through all the items in 'numUsers' and if the sum of them is less then 's' they should be appended to the list 'minn'.
But this is not working.

```
s, n = list(map(int, input().split()))
numUsers = []
count = 0
for i in range(n):
    numUsers.append(int(input()))
    
numUsers.sort()

minn = []

if sum(numUsers) == s:
    print(n)
elif (s - sum(numUsers) < 0):
    for i in numUsers:
        while sum(minn) < s:
            minn.append(i)
            count += 1
print(count)
```

for the input:

- 100 3
- 50
- 30
- 50

According to the logic, I have 130 as sum(numUsers) which is way bigger than 's'. It is sorted so it must be [30, 50, 50]. Probably there's something goes wrong after it gets 90 or something but I can't figure out what exactly.
I'm somehow getting 4 instead of 2. Can you please give me advice on what is wrong with the code or with the logic I used in solving the task. Thank you very much.

Comment: Why not using 0/1 knapsack and print the elements ? I think this is 0/1 knapsack problem.

Comment: @DeepakTripathi If I only knew what this is about

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This expression:

```
while sum(minn) < s:
```

...does not include the number you are about to add, so the condition should really be:

```
sum(minn) + i <= s:
```

Then, the `while` loop could potentially add the same value of `i` twice or more to the `minn` list, so it should just be an `if`.

```
if sum(minn) + i <= s:
```

There is another problem as well: when `sum(numUsers)` is less than `s`, your code returns 0.

You should change this:

```
if sum(numUsers) == s:
    print(n)
elif (s - sum(numUsers) < 0):
```

to this:

```
if sum(numUsers) <= s:
    print(n)
else:
```

... but you might even decide to skip those three lines completely, and just use what is in the `else` block.

Also, you do not really use `minn` for the output, so you could just keep a running sum instead of a list.

To avoid confusion, here is the full code with the above mentioned changes:

```
def solve(s, n, numUsers):
    numUsers.sort()
    count = 0
    runningSum = 0
    for i in numUsers:
        if runningSum + i > s:
            break
        runningSum += i
        count += 1
    return count
```

Example call:

```
s = 100 
n = 2
numUsers = [200, 30]
print(solve(s, n, numUsers))  # 1
```

Comment: @trincot--think you intended `if runningSum + i <= s:` not `while runningSum + i <= s:`. and can optionally add an `else break`.

Comment: In case you have data like:
100 2
200
30
The answer will be: 3

Comment: Are you saying the answer *should* be 3?? Because this code will answer 1, since only 30 can be selected into the sum. See it run [on repl.it](https://repl.it/@trincottrincots/httpsstackoverflowcoma635576655459839)

Answer (score 0):

Possible changes:

```
summ = 0
newList = sorted(numUsers)

for i in range(len(newList)):
    summ += newList[i]
    count += 1
    if summ > s:
        count -= 1
        break
print(count)
```

Comment: How is this simpler than what I answered?

Comment: Not simpler. I wrote below the previous comment that in the case of data: 100 2 200 30 it will give you 3 as the result instead of 1. @trincot

Comment: And did you read my comment? My code does not return 3. You must have done something wrong in your implementation. Did you check the link I posted? Also, in this answer you write "simpler changes". Hence my question.

Comment: Now I see. My bad. @trincot